# No error code for warning in output window

Tags: warnings, suppress-warnings, error-code

I have a warning in visual studio saying the referenced component 'project name' could not be found.  All I want is the error code to suppress the warning, but the only place, from what I've read, to find it is in the output window.  In my visual studio this error code/warning isn't listed in the output window.  So where else can I find an error code for a warning if not in the output window?